# Sumologic: How to get average time difference between two messages

Tags: sumologic

Having a set of logs like:

```
Log10:[requestId=2][taskId=C][message='End']
Log9: [requestId=2][taskId=C][message='Start']
Log8: [requestId=2][taskId=B][message='End']
Log7: [requestId=1][taskId=B][message='End']
Log6: [requestId=1][taskId=B][message='Start']
Log5: [requestId=1][taskId=A][message='End']
Log4: [requestId=2][taskId=B][message='Start']
Log3: [requestId=2][taskId=A][message='End']
Log2: [requestId=2][taskId=A][message='Start']
Log1: [requestId=1][taskId=A][message='Start']
```

First, I wanted to calculate the avg time each task takes to complete. I was able to that with transactionize:

```
* | concat(requestId,":",taskId) as transactionKey | transactionize transactionKey avg(_group_duration) group by taskId
```

Now, I'm willing to know how much time (avg) is happening between one task finishes and the next one is starting.

In this concrete example, my desired output would be:

```
((Log9 - Log8) + (Log4 - Log3) + (Log6 - Log5)) / 3
```

Any clue is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the complete answer, but it probably involves using the `diff` operator applied to the `_messagetime` field. This will allow you to find the time between subsequent messages.

Comment: @chadoliver yes sr, that did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chadoliver, he pointed me to the diff operator.

```
* | keyvalue auto | diff _messagetime by requestId | where message = "End" | avg(_diff) | ceil(_avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex, avg and group by functions to get aggregate results.

```
_sourceCategory="dev/test-app"
and "[Error]"
and "Error occurred"
| formatDate(_receiptTime, "yyyy-MM-dd") as date
| parse regex field=_raw "Error occurred. Exception:(?<message> \w.*)" nodrop
| replace(message,/my custom error message: ([0-9A-Fa-f\-]{36})/,"my custom error message") as replaceMessage
| parse regex field=_raw "\[Error](?<otherMessage> \w.*)" nodrop
| if (replaceMessage = "", otherMessage, replaceMessage ) as  consolidatedMessage
| if (length(consolidatedMessage)> 150,substring(consolidatedMessage,0, 150),consolidatedMessage) as  finalMessage
| count date, finalMessage
| transpose row data column finalMessage
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxzp7G-rUh8